# Return key creating too high a line height in PS CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am using Photoshop version CS5.  My keyboard return button is not working properly; it's spacing too much.

What should I do?  Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the "Leading" setting, it is probably set to a very high value. Set it to "Auto" to begin with, then adjust to fit your needs. It will be under the "Character" attributes, see the image below.

[image]